# URL Regular Expression mismatch

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn Django and I am currently stuck in an issue.

I created an app Contact and run the server, I get the error.

The error page displayed by server:

[image]

The urls.py file in the app Contact

urls.py in conatct

[image]

When the pattern in urls.py is 
urlpatterns =[url(r'^$', views.form, name ='form')]
it works properly, but not with other pattern shown in the picture

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post actual, formatted code and error messages, no links to images. This makes it easier to read your question and for others to find it.

Comment: Why are you expecting `contact/` to match `form/`?

Answer (score 0):

The *Page not found* error message tells you what went wrong: For the URL (*/contact*) you requested, Django was unable to find a suitable view. Because you have debugging enabled, you get some information, including a list of registered views.

First things first: You probably have `url(r'^contact/', include('contact.urls'))` somewhere in your top level `urls.py`. This makes the URLs defined in the `contact/urls.py` available under the prefix `/contact`.

With

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^form/', views.form, name='form'),
]
```

in `contact/urls.py` you are telling Django that you want urls starting with `contact/form/` to be handled by `views.form`.

Consequently, when you access http://localhost:8000/contact/ in your browser, there is no view associated with that URL, hence the 404. Your view is *reacting to* to http://localhost:8000/contact/form, not http://localhost:8000/contact.

When you change the URL pattern to

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.form, name='form'),
]
```

you modify the URL `views.form` reacts to.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand it